# How to run a script certain time using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron

whenever `readDirectory` invoked i am checking if any file created Date is past 30 days i want to remove that file from direcotry. This is working as expected and removing the files but i dont think its efficient. So I want to move `comapreDates` method to separate file and call directory `logs/St` every night and check if any file expired passed 30 days period remove it. is it doable ?

service.js

```
function readDirectory(callback) {
    var dirPath = './logs/St';
    var files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath);
    async.eachSeries(files, function(file, callback) {
        var filePath = path.join(dirPath, file);
        var fileInfo = {};
        fs.stat(filePath, function(err, stats) {
            if (err) {
                console.info("File doesn't");
            } else {
                fileInfo.fileDate = stats.birthtime;
                fileInfo.filename = file;
                compareDates(fileInfo, filePath);
                objToReturn.push(fileInfo);
                callback();
            }
        });
    }, function(err) {
        //final callback when all files completed here send objToReturn to client
        callback(objToReturn);
    });
}
}

function compareDates(file, path) {
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(currentDate.getTime() - file.fileDate.getTime());
    var dayDifference = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
    console.log('Days', dayDifference);
    console.log('FileName', file.filename);
    if (dayDifference >= 30) {
        fs.unlink(path, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                // file doens't exist
                console.info("File doesn't exist, won't remove it.");
            } else {
                console.log('removed file', file);
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

See one of those modules:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron-job

and more modules here:

- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/schedule
- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/cron
- https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/job